# Change color of lists in a CSS stylesheet

Tags: html, css

So I have some code for some ordered lists in html and I'm trying to make a stylesheet that adds in different colors for each depths added.

For instance:

```
<ol>
 <li>This is red</li>
  <ol>
   <li>This is blue</li>
  </ol>
</ol>
```

How do I do this with a CSS stylesheet?

tried something like this:

```
ol.a {
 color:blue;
}
ol.b {
 color:red;
}
```

obviously it didn't work or else I'd not be here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer:

```
ol {
 color:blue;
}
ol ol {
 color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

HTML:

```
<ol class="a">
 <li>This is red</li>
  <ol class="b">
   <li>This is blue</li>
  </ol>
</ol>
```

CSS:

```
ol.a {
 color:red;
}
ol.b {
 color:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is the correct css

```
ol li {
 color:blue;
}
ol li ol li {
 color:red;
}
```

Comment: My version is simpler, as it doesn't refer to the `li` elements

Answer (score 1):

You can apply css on your ol this way -

```css
ol > ol:nth-child(2) {
  background-color:red;
}

ol > ol:nth-child(3) {
  background-color:blue;
}

ol > ol:nth-child(4) {
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<ol>
 <li>This is red</li>
 <ol>
   <li>This is blue</li>
 </ol>
 <ol>
   <li>This is blue</li>
 </ol>
  <ol>
   <li>This is blue</li>
 </ol>
  
</ol>
```